# MultiBinding to the Title Property of a wpf user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I need to format the Title property of my user control. For this I am trying to make use of MultiBinding with StringFormat.

The Xaml I use is :

```
<Control x:Name="myControlName">
    <Control.Title>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="You have {0} of {1} items. ">
            <Binding Path="MyNumber"></Binding>
            <Binding Path="TotalNumber"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Control.Title>
</Control>
```

For some reason this does not seem to work.
Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Hey...Thanks Joey...I couldnt get the code tags properly ... :)

Comment: Yep, that was obvious ;-). There is also a nice »code« button in the toolbar above the editor. It's just broken in IE 9 beta for now.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ?.I didn't get what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend binding the Title property to a property on a ViewModel if using MVVM or just a property on the code behind if not.

```
<Control x:Name="myControlName" Title={Binding Path=MyTitle}>

</Control>

public class MyView
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalNumber { get; set; }
    public string MyTitle 
    {
        get { return string.Format("You have {0} of {1} items. ", MyNumber, TotalNumber); }
    }
}
```